# Авторизация через VK Api

Tags: android, android-sdk, vkontakte-api

Делаю авторизацию в приложении через vk api(официальное vk android sdk). Проблема в том, что я не могу понять логику работы с токеном. Насколько я помню на php(на сайтах) это делается просто. Отправляется запрос с параметрами, оно перенаправляет на сайт ВК для разрешения доступа, если true, тогда возвращает назад с json данными (id, токен). Далее токен нужно использовать в запросах.На андроид получение токена ещё ясно. Его можно взять из метода

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (!VKSdk.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new VKCallback <VKAccessToken> () {
            @Override
            public void onResult(VKAccessToken res) {
                // Пользователь успешно авторизовался
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(VKError error) {
                // Произошла ошибка авторизации (например, пользователь запретил авторизацию)
            }
        })) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

И что с ним делать? Как его использовать в api запросах. На оф. сайте пишет пример запроса:

```
VKRequest request = VKApi.users().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.USER_IDS, "1,2"));
```

Где здесь токен?

Answer (score 2):

Я конечно не знаток по данному языку программирования, но в запрос нужно ещё добавить:

`VKApiConst.ACCESS_TOKEN`

Comment: И что? Так можно записать токен в константу?

Comment: Нет она final. Просто я хочу использовать api методы со своим токеном(не тем, который получаю через авторизацию).

Comment: Ну вообще, да. Это же ведь параметр api, такой же как и user_ids, только access_token. Может вообще, токен там уже сам передаётся, так как в примерах нет с ним ничего.

Answer (score 0):

Ну вообщето токен оно само вставляет и явно его посылать не нужно. Но если вам он так нужен то в OnResult напишите res.AssesToken, возвращает String.

Answer (score 0):

Использовать свой token можно двумя способами:

1. Нужно в запрос добавить еще пару значений: "access_token" и new_token.
   Пример:

   ```
   VKRequest request = VKApi.users().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.USER_IDS, "1,2", "access_token", new_token));
   ```
2. Вызвать VKSDK.SetAccessToken(token, renew). renew - флаг (в саппорте написано: "Is token being renewed. Raises different event handlers")